# Pass data from a parent component to child component inside provider & consumer in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a parent component where I have to use broadcasting in parent component. I would like to pass the data using providers and consumer in this child component. I want to have child component to passed in value in the parent component using this providers and consumer. I would then use the providers and consumer of this parent to child component to callback methods.

Can someone please help with an example? How should I solve this problem? I'm very new to react-redux.

Here is the code:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import { createContext } from "react-broadcast";

// using CommonJS modules

const users = [{ name: "HITACHI" }, { name: "MGRM NET" }];

const { Provider, Consumer } = createContext(users[0]);

class UpdateBlocker extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currentUser: Provider.defaultValue
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * users.length);
      this.setState({ currentUser: users[index] });
    }, 2000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Provider value={this.state.currentUser}>
          <UpdateBlocker>
            <Consumer>
              {currentUser => <p>The current user is {currentUser.name}</p>}
            </Consumer>
          </UpdateBlocker>
        </Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code. Also look at react-context api. Also you can check  [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49629953/how-to-change-react-context-programatically/49630177#49630177) post and [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context)

Comment: Here is an example of how to use context: https://codesandbox.io/s/9z06xzlyly

Comment: What problem do you face with the above code.

Comment: actually I am asking how to update context in using componentDidUpdate() component, context is showing in the render.

Comment: componentDidUpdate() {

  let value = this.context;

  }

Comment: context data is showing in consumer in the render function but context data is not showing it in componentDidUpdate(), so how to update context data in the componentDidUpdate() component.